# Expanding function into Maclaurin series

Tags: functions

How to expand that function below into Maclaurin series? Is it even possible?
$$
f(x)=x^2+\ln\left(\frac{2x-3}{5-3x}\right)
$$
I know that expanding into Maclaurin series requires function class $C^\infty$ in some surrounding of $0$. 
In this case, I checked $f(0)$ and got $\ln(-3/5)$ as a result, which is not specified in domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $x\in(\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3})$ this function is valid. so strictly speaking you cannot expand it via maclaurin series.but you can expand it using taylor expansion about a point $a$ where $a\in(\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{3})$ . although if you want to use maclaurin function only you can split the log term into two , i.e $\ln(2x-3)-\ln(5-3x)$ and then individually apply maclurin and add them